# Following services are not running: web

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I'm getting the following error while deploying (express+react) application using node server on elactic beabstalk

ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
Impaired services on all instances.

Process default has been unhealthy for 4 hours 33 minutes (Target.ResponseCodeMismatch).
Following services are not running: web.

Comment: Have you inspected any EB logs? Have you sshed into the instance to check if your app, web server are working?

Comment: its running with its initial settings ..but degrades when i deploy my application using pipeline ..codepipeline is successfully deployed ..but beanstalks shows this error

Comment: @Siddharth did you ever figure this out? Running into the same thing.

Comment: Did you figure this? @Jarad

Comment: @Rukshan I did, but the way I did it was really complicated. I noticed in one of the log files that the status code of the EB health checker was not 200, and it was due to load balancer listener rules. I used an .ebextensions config file to configure the listeners. [More info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html)